# Looking up a hostname for a given path and client ID

Tags: java

I have this code in my library and I wanted to see whether we can avoid duplicating stuff.

```
private String getAddress(final String path, final int clientId) {
    if (TestUtils.isEmpty(mapping) || TestUtils.isEmpty(mapping.get(path))  || TestUtils.isEmpty(mapping.get(path).get(clientId))) {
        logger.logError("mapping must not be empty. full path= ", path, ", clientId= ", clientId, ", Mapping= ",
                mapping);
        return null;
    }
    final int localId = mapping.get(path).get(clientId);
    final String hostname = getHostname(path, localId);
    return hostname;
}
```

Here mapping is defined as,

```
private final Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> mapping;
```

Is there anything we can improve in the above code? I do see duplicated stuff as I am checking in the `if` statement and then using same thing just below it.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what does the `TestUtils.isEmpty` method do?

Comment: They just check emptiness of various datatypes.. String, Collection, Map..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't duplicate it:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> intermediate = mapping.get(path);
if (intermediate != null) {
    Integer localId = intermediate.get(clientId);
    if (localId != null) {
        return getHostname(path, localId);
    }
}

// log error here
return null;
```

Alternatively, you could throw the above into a helper function:

```
private Integer getLocalId(String path, int clientId)
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> intermediate = mapping.get(path);
    if (intermediate != null) {
        return intermediate.get(clientId);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then have just the one check:

```
private String getAddress(final String path, final int clientId) {
    Integer localId = getLocalId(path, clientId);
    if (localId == null) {
        // error
        return null;
    }

    return getHostname(path, localId);
}
```

Comment: One of your `return null`s don't have a ending semicolon.

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup You have the rep, you could've added it :)

Comment: I really don't like editing code on answers or questions; if you think I should, then I will: *on yours posts only*.

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup I mean, don't completely rearrange logic or anything. But if it's fixing typos? Yeah, of course, have at it.

Answer (score 2):

With some Java 8 magic, you can use `Optional` and some repeated `map` and `filter` to get your result.

```
Optional<Integer> localId = Optional.ofNullable(mapping)
    .filter(TestUtils::isNotEmpty)
    .map(m -> m.get(path))
    .filter(TestUtils::isNotEmpty)
    .map(m -> m.get(clientId))
    .filter(TestUtils::isNotEmpty);

if (!localId.isPresent()) {
    logger.logError("mapping must not be empty. full path= ",
         path, ", clientId= ", clientId, ", Mapping= ", mapping);
    return null;
}
final String hostname = getHostname(path, localId.get());
return hostname;
```

Here, the `TestUtils.isNotEmpty(...)` method is the negation of your existing `TestUtils.isEmpty(...)`.

Comment: I am still on Java 7. Do you think i can still use guava optional here instead of Java 8?

Comment: @user1950349 while you could do that, you wouldn't really gain anything as you couldn't use Java 8's neat lambdas.